# connecting sybase IQ using Node.js

Tags: node.js, driver, sybase, sap-iq

I am trying to connect to sybase IQ database using Node.js,
I am using below script:

```
> var Sybase = require('sybase'),
>     db = new Sybase('10.29.11.190', 2640 , 'dbo', 'dcbo', 'dcbo');
> 
> db.connect(function (err) {
>     if (err) return console.log(err);
> 
>     db.query('SELECT * from table1',
> function (err, data) {
>         if (err) console.log(err);
> 
>         console.log(data);
> 
>         db.disconnect();
> 
>     }); });
```

but I recieve below error:

```
[Error: Error: Unable to access jarfile ./JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar]
```

Am I using correct package? can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/sybase? The above mentioned seems to be default path, you can however configure `javaJarPath` to point it to the correct JAR file.

Comment: I corrected the path to the jar file and now I am getting another error:      ** Error: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -265: Procedure 'sp_helpdb' not found **

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to Sybase IQ, you can use the [SQL Anywhere driver](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/node-sqlanywhere):

```
var sqla = require('sqlanywhere');
db = sqla.createConnection( { 'Host': '10.29.11.190:2640',
                              'dbn': 'dbo',
                              'uid': 'dcbo',
                              'pwd': 'dcbo' } );
```